# Compare two identical folders on two different machines, SSH issue

Tags: python, compare

So i got two (supposed) to be equal very big folders on two machines.
I want to compare their file sizes for each file in the folder.
Every once in a while files that should be equal are not, and one of the files is smaller then it should be.

The compare is easy and widely explained on the net, but how is the shh connectivity done ? that is my Q.
What is the best practice ?
Thanks

Comment: If you're on unix just use `diff`. Something like:  `diff -arq folder1 folder2` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644593/unix-compare-two-folders-which-has-many-files-inside-contents

Comment: iterate over the pair files and return False if two sizes does not match else return True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a real compare but anyway:

```
import subprocess
f_pass ='pswd'
f_ip = '10.10.10.10'
f_user = 'root'
f_folder = '/tmp/'
s_pass ='pswd'
s_ip = '10.10.10.11'
s_user = 'root'
s_folder = '/tmp/'

f_cmd = "sshpass -p '{}' ssh {}@{} find  {} -ls".format(f_pass, f_user, f_ip, f_cmp_folder)
s_cmd = "sshpass -p '{}' ssh {}@{} find  {} -ls".format(s_pass, s_user, s_ip, s_cmp_folder)

f_result = subprocess.check_output(f_cmd, shell=True)
s_result = subprocess.check_output(s_cmd, shell=True)
```

Now you can do what u want with the output of the find command, you may also compare them ...